# Datagrid cell formatting not retain after user edit?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagrid

i have a datagrid with the following cell formatting

```
datagrid.rows[0].cells[0].Value =1;
datagrid.rows[0].cells[0].Style.Format ="#k";
```

this works fine and the output will be 1k, however when the user edit the cell value example to 2 then cell formatting will not take effect?

question is how can i retain the cell formatting after user edit?

thanks

Comment: Are you trying to set the style for a unique cell (at [0,0]) or for the entire column?

Comment: just for cell[0,0] for now for simplicity, i know you can set a style format for entire column using datagrid.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format ="";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are not working with an underlying datasource. You are inserting `DataGridViewRows` manually into the `DataGridView`.

If you were using a datasource, if the column datatype was numeric, the styling will work in both edit and readonly modes.

In your case, you need to handle the `CellFormatting` event of the `DataGridView` and set the format of your cell there:

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender,
                                  DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex == 0)
    {
        // if the underlying type is int
        int value;
        if(e.Value != null && int.TryParse(e.Value.ToString(), out value))
        {
            e.Value = value.ToString("#k");

            /*** OR ***

            e.Value = value;
            e.CellStyle.Format = "#k";

            */
        }
    }
}
```